# Spark sql save dataframe to hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am using java to write some sparksql code.I have a class like below:

```
public class Item_Meta {

private String itemId;
private String category;
private String description;
private String properties;}
```

And then  I **create a Dataset called dataset from a List of Item_Meta** by below statement:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.sqlContext().createDataFrame(list, Item_Meta.class)
```

And then **called dataset.show()**,I get this:

```
+--------+-----------+------+----------+
|category|description|itemId|properties|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+
|       1|      item1|     1|avgGrade1|
|       1|      item2|     2|avgGrade2|
|       1|      item3|     3|avgGrade3|
|       1|      item4|     4|avgGrade4|
|       1|      item5|     5|avgGrade5|
+--------+-----------+------+----------+
```

This looks OK as I have item id range from 1 to 5, category all 1,description is "item"+id...

Then I **save this Dataset to hive**,using below statement:

```
saveSql="INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE "+tableName+" PARTITION(ds='"+ds+"') select * from dataset"
```

It worked but When I query hive table,I get this:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
|item_id|category|description|properties|        ds|
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
|      1|   item1|          1|avgGrade1|2017-10-26|
|      1|   item2|          2|avgGrade2|2017-10-26|
|      1|   item3|          3|avgGrade3|2017-10-26|
|      1|   item4|          4|avgGrade4|2017-10-26|
|      1|   item5|          5|avgGrade5|2017-10-26|
+-------+--------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

As you can see,the problem is **datas are not in right colomn**. How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of columns is important while performing an `INSERT OVERWRITE`.

You'll have to change your query to look something like this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename
PARTITION(ds = '2017-10-26')
SELECT
  itemId,
  category,
  description,
  properties
from
  dataset
```